# how do i prevent downloading duplicate file for normanization

Tags: java, xml, file, http, download

Sending the request to Server with the below xml for downloading

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceSet xmlns:v01"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <cycleTime>123</cycleTime>
    <object>
        <sourceUrl>http://10.34894.494/23.png</sourceUrl>
         <accessUrl>http://10.126.45.72/cme/23.png</accessUrl>
        <objectMetadata>
            <headerName>Content-Length</headerName>
            <headerName>E-Tag</headerName>
        </objectMetadata>
    </object> 
    <object>
        <sourceUrl>http://10.84375.72/cme/23.png</sourceUrl>
         <accessUrl>http://10.4575.572/cme/logo/23.png</accessUrl>
        <objectMetadata>
            <headerName>Content-Length</headerName>
            <headerName>E-Tag</headerName>
        </objectMetadata>
    </object> 
</ResourceSet>
```

There are 2 objects and which has same source URL and different Access URl .
My job is to download the image only once because source URL’s are duplicated .

Am iterating through the objects , but how I will know two objects has same source URL to download ?

There are 2 objects and which has same source URL and different Access URl .
My job is to download the image only once because source URL’s are duplicated .

Am iterating through the objects , but how I will know two objects has same source URL to download ?

```
public void download_resourceset_object_urls_images_to_local() throws Throwable {
    List<String> sourceURis = GFDUtils.getSourceOrAccessURLs(xmlPath + xmlFileName, "sourceUrl");
    dwInfoList = new HashMap<String, DownloadFileInfo>();
    NSAUtils.removeFiles(ConfigLoader.DOWNLOAD_DIR);
    boolean flag = HTTPClientFileDownload.downloadFile(sourceURis, ConfigLoader.DOWNLOAD_DIR, dwInfoList);
    if (flag == true) {
        logger.info("All URL files / images are downloaded successfully....");
    } else
        throw new GenericException("Files are not available / Failed download ");
}
```

here am iterating Xml and getting the Source URL to download

```
public static List<String> getSourceOrAccessURLs(String xmlPath, String urlname) throws IOException {
        XStream xs = new XStream();
        boolean flag = XMLValidation.validateXMLSchema(xmlPath);
        File file = new File(xmlPath);
        String xml = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
        if (flag == true) {
            List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                xs.processAnnotations(Resourceset.class);
                Resourceset rs = (Resourceset) xs.fromXML(xml);
                List<ResourcesetObject> rsoOject = rs.getResourcesetObject();
                for (ResourcesetObject resourcesetObject : rsoOject) {

                    if (urlname.equals("sourceUrl")) {

                        urls.add(resourcesetObject.getSourceUrl());

                    } else {
                        urls.add(resourcesetObject.getAccessUrl());
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return urls;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This URL Am passing for downloading.

Please help

Thanks,

Comment: The two objects in your example do not have the same source URL.  Is this a typo?

Comment: If you use a Set instead of a List for your URIs, you will have only unique entries.

Comment: Yes Its the typo. Sorry .

Comment: <object>
        <sourceUrl>http://10.34894.494/23.png</sourceUrl>
         <accessUrl>http://10.126.45.72/cme/23.png</accessUrl>
        <objectMetadata>
            <headerName>Content-Length</headerName>
            <headerName>E-Tag</headerName>
        </objectMetadata>
    </object> 
    <object>
        <sourceUrl>http://10.34894.494/23.png</sourceUrl>
         <accessUrl>http://10.4575.572/cme/logo/23.png</accessUrl>
    </object>